# Facebook FB.login won't ask the user for email permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My website uses Facebook Authentication. Everything works fine, except I can't seem to get the user's email. I am using this function:

```
 onclick="FB.login(function(response){},{perms:\'email\'});"
```

Which indeed prompts the user for his permissions, but not for his email (I tried adding other special permissions and that didn't work).

Of course, later on when I user FB.api('/me'), I don't get the user's email.
My page can be found [here](http://www.funcampuses.com/rate).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's not `perms` it's `scope`

```
 onclick="FB.login(function(response){},{scope:\'email\'});"
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: @Aviv: Looking to your code, if you want to use `scope` parameter you should set `oauth` to true in `FB.init()`. Also your `FB.login` method in `onclick` is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're not initialising the Facebook JavaScript SDK - none of the calls to FB methods will work without it happening. You can do this using:

```
<script>               
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });
    };
</script>
```

Put this in your source after:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And as @steveax has already stated you need to use `scope` and not `perms` for your permissions.